# Update UI from AsyncCallback

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have problems updating my UITableView from an AsyncCallback but updating a label works fine?
My code looks like this:

```
    private void ProcessHttpResponse(IAsyncResult iar) {
                    // Do some work ...

        InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
            myTable.Source = new MyTableViewSource(this.Controller,result.Messages);
            txtInfo.Text += "Received request from: ";
        });
    }
```

Do I need to do something else with my table besides setting the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isnt there a ReloadData() or something on the myTable.Source?

I would also add a bit more validation of the response before adding it to the datasource, and bung it all in a nice try / catch :)

Comment: Ah ReloadData() solved it, thanks for your help and the try / catch is there I just left that out of the example :)